# How to make cookie read only

Tags: cookies, readonly

How to make cookie secure i.e user should not be able to modify the cookie value in application developers or he should not be allowed to delete the cookie from there.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, since cookies are stored user's device they can delete it or do whatever they want with it.